# How to filter information from a list of structs

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, struct

I have a list of structs like this `list<color> colorList;`

```
  `  struct color {
       int r;
       int g;
       int b;
     }`
```

My requirement is to have a map but to have the capability to look up 'color' having the same RGB values.
Eg. All 'color' with r=128,g=128,b=0.

My instinct is to create a map whose key is r,g,b, and value are the structs whose RGB values match.

I am looking for a performance optimal solution in c++.

Comment: You say you need to "look up colors", but what additional information do you want to attach to a color? Right now you're just storing the `color` again, but a `std::map<color, color>` contains the same information as a `std::set<color>`.

Comment: Hello Botje, I guess I was not clear in my question. My query could be  'retrieve all with r=128'. it should retrieve all structs matching that criteria irrespective b,g values.

Comment: @Vijay Are you sure you want to implement a map? Or maybe a set? With a map and set the key is unique. But do you want that? Perhaps you just need to find the `color` objects in your list.

Comment: @jignatiusIt is not mandatory for me to use a map. I need to get color objects based on partially matching values (eg. only red = 128).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a library called Linq, in c# it allows you to filter the result of a query on a database.
The library is called Linq++ (https://github.com/hjiang/linqxx/wiki), for your code you should use the method called where and filter if the color is greater than what are you searching for.
THe methor where allows you to search also for multiple condition putting & like red > 128 & green > 128